# Computing expectation of $\frac{X}{X+Y}$ using moment generating functions only

Tags: probability-distributions, moment-generating-functions

I have two positive, independent, absolutely continuous random variables $X$ and $Y$ with their moment generating functions $M_X$ and $M_Y$. In Foata Fuchs, there is an exercise stating
$$\mathbb E\Big[\frac{X}{X+Y}\Big]=-\int_{\mathbb R}M_X'(t) M_Y(t)\,dt.$$

Trying this for $X,Y\sim Exp(1)$, implies $M_X(t)=M_Y(t)=(1-t)^{-1}$. These functions are only defined for $|t|<1$. Furthermore, $M'_X(t)=(1-t)^{-2}$. And finally
$$-\int_{\mathbb R}\frac{1}{(1-t)^3}\,dt.$$
This integral, however, does not converge.

However,
$$\mathbb E\Big[\frac{X}{X+Y}\Big]=\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty\frac{x}{x+y}e^{-(x+y)}\,dxdy$$

I do know
$$\frac{1}{x+y}=-\int_0^\infty e^{-(x+y)t}dt$$

Provided, I can exchange the integrals, that should give me the answer above... What is wrong with this formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm, I looked through the book and there seems to be confusion in the notation and functions involved. The book suggests in particular that
$$
\mathbb{E}\left(  \frac{X}{X+Y}\right) = -\int_{\mathbb{R}^{+}} g_1'(u) g_2(u)du
$$
where
$$
g_1'(u) = \frac{d}{du} \mathbb{E}(e^{-uX}), \quad g_2(u) = \mathbb{E}(e^{-uY})
$$
let's calculate all this
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}(e^{-uX}) & = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-ux} e^{-x} dx = \frac{1}{1+u} \\
\frac{d}{du} \mathbb{E}(e^{-uX}) & = - \frac{1}{(1+u)^2}
\end{align*}
we use the formula
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}\left(  \frac{X}{X+Y}\right)&  = -\int_{\mathbb{R}^{+}} g_1'(u) g_2(u)du \\
& = -\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{-1}{(1+u)^2} \frac{1}{1+u} du \\
& = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(1+u)^3} du \\
& = -\frac{1}{2(1+x)^2} \Big|_{0}^{\infty} \\
& = 1/2
\end{align*}
Using what you suggest we can do the following
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x}{x+y} e^{-x-y} dydx  & = \int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty}  x e^{-x-y} e^{-t(x+y)} dtdydx \\ 
& = \int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} x e^{-(x+y)(t+1)} dtdydx \\
 & = \int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} x e^{-(x+y)(t+1)} dydxdt \\
& = \int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x e^{-x(t+1)}}{t+1} dxdt \\
& = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(t+1)^3} dt \\
& = 1/2
\end{align*}

Comment: Indeed, I was thinking of g(u)=E(exp(uX)), not of E(exp(-uX)). No wonder it did not work.